# How do you read <Binary data> from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. One of our columns contains `<Binary data>` as the values. How can I read what the actual value is?

Comment: Read it how? In a PowerShell script? In VBA?

Comment: I need to know what the value is. So anyway I can get the value does not matter what I use just so I get the value. Thanks

Comment: Get it how? It's _binary_. What do you need to _do_ with it?

Comment: I look in the cell in the column in the database and all I see is <binary data> I want to know what that string value is.

Comment: It's not a string value. It's a _binary_ value. Just bits. ones and zeros. It could be a photograph, for instance.